# How does one enable/disable inline bot use in Telegram chats?

Tags: permissions, bots, telegram-messenger

Attempting to use inline bots (including official ones such as `@gif` and `@pic`) in a specific Telegram group chat I'm in fails, regardless of the sender.  Depending on various factors, including the client used, the panel that normally pops up from inline bot usage could instead display either the error message "Posting inline content isn't allowed in this group" or the error message "#400: CHAT_SEND_INLINE_FORBIDDEN"; if no error message displays, the media will show up in the chat, but with an error icon indicating a failed send.  Behavior such as the above is observed by all of the chat's members when posting to this group using any inline bot, but isn't seen by members posting to other groups using the same inline bots (ruling out user-specific and bot-specific issues).

[image: Screenshot by Kyli Rogue: "Posting inline content isn't allowed in this group."]
[image: Screenshot by hex: "#400: CHAT_SEND_INLINE_FORBIDDEN"]
[image: Screenshot by Phyxius: failed send]

The owner of this chat is willing to change this permission for the chat, but there doesn't seem to be a corresponding UI option in that chat's settings for this permission.

[image: Screenshot by Kay Fox: Telegram chat member permissions, with all but "Pin messages" and "Change group info" enabled]

Telegram's UI doesn't seem to have a clear means of enabling or disabling the use of inline bots on either Windows's or Android's updated clients, and the error message of "Posting inline content isn't allowed in this group" is (as of this posting) [incredibly](https://www.google.com/search?q=telegram%20%22posting%20inline%20content%20isn%27t%20allowed%20in%20this%20group%22) [unGoogleable](https://www.google.com/search?q=telegram+disable+inline+bots); most of the 7 results are from Telegram's localization website.

Where in Telegram's UI can the use of inline bots be enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 1):

This issue seems to be due to a bug on the Telegram server's end.  The bugged permission state can be fixed by disabling the "Send Stickers & GIFs" permission for chat members, and then re-enabling that same permission.  A chat owner or a chat admin with the admin permission to edit chat permissions will need to perform this action.

The cause for this bugged chat permission is not yet known.